# How to set report parameter properties based on previous parameter value

Tags: reporting-services

How do I set the selecting of a report parameters in ssrs to default to a different selection based on options selected.

I have a report that have up to 5 radio buttons in my parameter field and the query is such that if one value is true another should be false so users want that when they select a certain radio button, another should default to false.

In Chose default value for this parameter I used a switch function but not getting it right. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this in SSRS.  I'd take care of this in drop downs so you can pass in a parameter to a query to dynamically change what will appear, even if it's just two vaues.

You do this by:

1) Add queries for parent and child datasets

2) Add parameters for parent and child, getting available values from the datasets

3) Reference parent parameter in child dataset

The parameters will now cascade.

Comment: Thank you! I understand setting parameters to get available values from a dataset but in this case, the values are not really coming from a database so creating drop down value parameters are not feasible.

Comment: Just write it in SQL, e.g. select 'value1' union select 'value2' etc.  If needed you could also throw in if/case to change what you get from a parameter.

Comment: Another option is the available values in the hard coded list instead of a query.